# Hyper-V Test Bed for Forefront TMG 2010 Networking Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, hyper-v, dhcp, rras

I am trying to set up a Server 2008 R2 test bed for a Forefront TMG 2010 deployment and I can't seem to get the networking configured correctly. The set up is as follows:

Hyper-V Host has two NICs, both with public, static IPs and internet connections.

I have two virtual networks, one of connection type "Internal" for communication between servers. The other is type "External" using one of the hardware gigabit adapters I have installed.

I have 3 VMs running. I am trying to configure RRAS and DHCP on one VM to provide private addresses and internet connections to the other VMs. The DHCP/RRAS server has two NICs, one on the internal virtual network and one on the external. The other two only have one NIC and they are assigned to the internal virtual network

I have static, public IPs for all of the adapters. I am not getting an internet connection on the two VMs that are relying on DHCP. I know I'm missing something here. I've done it once before on VMWare Workstation but I can't seem to get this setup working on Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing I would try is to manually configure a vm on the internal network using the router you have configured as a gateway.  If that works you know there is a problem with your DHCP config, if it doesn't you can begin troubleshooting the routing table on the RRAS server.

Comment: Does NAT depend explicitly on DHCP? I have done some reconfiguration and I am not using DHCP. All clients have static public addresses. I am within a medium sized network at my university and so my installation of TMG is technically a "back firewall", however, it is acting as the edge firewall to my test domain. Could this cause issues?